# Regex matching everything in a sentence starting with a number and a period and another period

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this text:

[image]

Using JavaScript, I am trying to develop a regex that matches the first 4 sentences, including any newline characters.

The closest I got to is `/([0-9])+.*/gm` but it's incomplete; It ignores the 2nd part of the sentence starting with "4." because of the `\n` character between the words `completed` and `tasks`. It only matches the part in blue on the screenshot.

Any ideas on how to include:

> "tasks and the last task that was submitted."

in the match?

---

***Edit 1:** Here's the text in the screenshot:*

1. It creates a directory for the log file if it doesn't exist.
2. It checks that the log file is newline-terminated.
3. It writes a newline-terminated JSON object to the log file.
4. It reads the log file and returns a dictionary with the set of completed

   tasks and the last task that was submitted.

Using `/^\d+\.[\w\W]*?(?=\n\n|\n\d+\.)/gm` as suggested in the 1st comment by @Wiktor Stribizew, works. However using this sample text, it doesn't (it's skipping the last line):

1. The extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
2. The command handler parses the user's selection and calls the explain function
3. The explain function returns a promise that resolves to the explanation
4. The command handler displays the explanation in a message box

[image]

---

***Edit 2:** To clarify, the regex needs to match any number of sentences starting with a number and a period and ending with a period. Sometimes it could be 4, and sometimes it could anything up to 20.*

---

Comment: Try `/^\d+\.[\w\W]*?(?=\n\n|\n\d+\.)/gm`

Comment: Please _delete_ the image and instead include the sample data as _text_, directly in your question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! It works with the sample text. However, it doesn't work with a different text, look at my Edited question please

Comment: So, you mean it can end there? `/^\d+\.[\w\W]*?(?=\n\n|\n\d+\.|$(?![\w\W]))/gm`?

Comment: Added a screenshot with you suggestion and result.

Comment: Then use `/^\d+\.[\w\W]*?\./gm`

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase the regex as `(?:.*?(?:\n|$)){1,4}`:

```js
var input = `1. Line One.
2. Line 2.
3. Line 3.
4. Lime 4.
blah blah blah`;

var lines = input.match(/(?:.*?(?:\n|$)){1,4}/)[0];
console.log(lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `^\d+\.[^\.]+\./gm` to match only lines that start with a digit, up to first dot, even if the dot is on subsequent line(s):

```js
const input = `Some preamble stuff to ignore.
1. It creates a directory for the log file if it doesn't exist.
2. It checks that the log file is newline-terminated.
3. It writes a newline-terminated JSON object to the log file.
4. It reads the log file and returns a dictionary with the set of completed
   tasks and the last task that was submitted.
Some more stuff to ignore`;

let result = input.match(/^\d+\.[^\.]+\./gm);
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
[
  "1. It creates a directory for the log file if it doesn't exist.",
  "2. It checks that the log file is newline-terminated.",
  "3. It writes a newline-terminated JSON object to the log file.",
  "4. It reads the log file and returns a dictionary with the set of completed\n   tasks and the last task that was submitted."
]
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of line
- `\d+` -- 1+ digits
- `\.` -- literal dot
- `[^\.]+` -- everything up to next dot
- `\.` -- literal dot
- `gm` -- `g` flag to match multiple times, `m` flag to match `^` at the beginning of a line